# Checkout to a Particular Commit Git Repo with Submodules

Tags: git, git-submodules

I know how to clone with submodules:

```
git clone GITREPO --recursive
```

What I need to do is then checkout the repo at a particular commit and update the submodules to that commit too (the submodules commits are different at main repo checkout commit than at HEAD). I am doing this on a build server within a batch script.

Comment: Do those commits in submodules have some tag or you just want to checkout to the state of the submodule wich corresponds to some particular commit in main module?

Comment: Just want the state of the submodule that corresponds to the main module commit I choose.

Comment: A perk of submodules turns out to be that when I go to a particular commit on my main module, the submodules go to that point in history too.